# In the Bhagavadgītā, what are some objections to its proposed solutions to the paradox of action?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, karma, samsara

For those un-familiar with indian philosophy, the Bhagavadgītā is a text that proposes a solution to the problem of rebirth. This problem of rebirth is as follows:

We are in an endless cycle of life and death, and we are in this cycle because we act, and thus create karma, thus perpetuating our cycle of rebirth. If we want to try and stop this cycle, it may seem logical to stop all action. However, this too is a kind of action, and so we have the problem that every action keeps you in this cycle, and you can't not take action.

The Bhagavadgītā proposes that the solution to this problem is that we should act in a different way, not refrain from acting. Only our body and mind are in this cycle, not our true selves. We should use our lives to be devoted to the divine, and every action would be free from desire. Only then will we achieve spiritual freedom.

My question is, what are some possible objections to this proposed solution from the Bhagavadgītā? How would this not help us achieve spiritual freedom? Thank you!

Comment: _"what are some possible objections to this proposed solution"_ Objections on the solution proposed by Krishna himself? Who in the world can dare to put his/her objection on Krishna's teaching?

Comment: Are you looking for non-Hindu criticism of the Bhagavad Gita, or Hindu criticism of the Bhagavad Gita, or what?

Comment: Not sure where you are coming from with this question. The Gita is one of the 3 Prasthanas, scriptures accepted by all Hindus. The words of Krishna are the words of God Himself.

Comment: Suggest you reread chapters 3 and 4 of the Gita to understand more fully what is meant by action and inaction.

Comment: If you stop action, how will you extinguish the already accumulated karma? Inaction at the wrong time is a definite path to forever remain in the endless cycle.

Answer (score 1):

This is my first answer and my knowledge is poor and likely incorrect :)

How would you implement it practically?

Say you go today to market to buy mangoes. Obviously you “desire” to eat mangoes. How would you say you are doing actions free from desires

So that could be a possible objection to this solution